# How to resize Bitmaps the optimal way in Android?

Tags: java, android, graphics

Suppose I have a hexagon:

[image: hexagon]

If I resize this to use it in my application which contains a grid of hexagons:

```
// ...
bgPaint = new Paint();
bgPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
bgPaint.setDither(true);

// ...
Bitmap coloredBackground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bg);

// ...
canvas.drawBitmap(coloredBackground, null, getAsRect(), bgPaint);
```

I get this:

[image: Hexagons]

`getAsRect()` returns a `Rect` object I use for drawing. What I want to achieve is to get rid of those transparent pixels at the edges. I think I'm doing something wrong but I could not find where so far. Do you have any idea how can I solve this problem?

I tried experimenting with dither and antialias but nothing changed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

3 suggestions:

## 1

Try this: Turn off the system's scaling when you decode the resource by setting [BitmapFactory.Options.inScaled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inScaled) to false:

```
Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inScaled = false;
Bitmap source = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.bg, options);
```

The `inScaled` flag should be turned off if you need a non-scaled version of the bitmap.

Then scale your bitmap with `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(...)`.

## 2

Another possible reason is that your tile's diagonal black lines contain different shades of grey:

This is a close up of your tile:

[image]

It's anti-aliased before it's resized. Any pixels not totally black may show up as lighter color in the resized lines. You could change your lines lines to be completely black (0xFF000000) and do anti-alias only after the resizing.

## 3

Another solution to this problem is to design your tile like so:

[image]

which avoids the problem of drawing two anti-aliased diagonal lines next to each other.

Comment: `BitmapFactory` doesn't seem to have a `createScaledBitmap` method. I'm using api level 9. Did you mean `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap`?

Comment: Your solution worked like a charm (approach 1 and 2 together)! 3 is not applicable here. It also speeded up the program since scaling happens only once.

Comment: Ah yes, good idea. There are also algorithms for drawing hex patterns if your interested, instead of using drawables. This a C# example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14948/Hexagonal-grid-for-games-and-other-projects-Part-1

Comment: Yea I know that. In fact I'm using drawables only because I need some graphics but I'm able to draw those hexagons without the graphics too.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont use this one instead?

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(decodedBitmap, targetWidth, targetHeight, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try a [hqx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hqx) resizing algorithm:

[image]
[image]

Alternatively, you could paint onto a bigger surface, and scale that surface altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I'm resizing images as follows:

```
    String url = ""; //replace with path to your image  
    int imageDimension = 48; // replace with required image dimension

    //decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(url), null, o);

    //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = imageDimension;
    int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
    int scale = 1;
    while(true){
        if(width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
            break;
        width_tmp /= 2;
        height_tmp /= 2;
        scale *= 2;
    }

    //decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    Drawable drawable =  new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(),    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(url), null, o2));
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing here; could you explain the code? Are you downsizing more than "REQUIRED_SIZE"?

Comment: Yeah, this code resizes images to new size (imageDimension * imageDimension).

Comment: I think you didn't understand my concerns.