# Unnecessary scaled image

Tags: java, android, bitmap, draw

When I want to draw image using following functions I always get exactly 3 times bigger image than it's source has. So if I want to have displayed size 1000x1000 I have to resize source image to 335x335 and then it will be uncutted.

```
screen = new Screen(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.rose1), 40, 200, 1000, 1000, 1);
```

Screen contructor in Screen.java:

```
public Screen (Bitmap res, int xPos, int yPos, int w, int h, int numFrames){
    super.x = xPos;
    super.y = yPos;
    height = h;
    width = w;
    Bitmap [] image = new Bitmap[numFrames];
    spritesheet = res;

    for (int i = 0; i<image.length; i++){
        image[i] = Bitmap.createBitmap(spritesheet, i*width, 0, width, height);
        //image[i] = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(spritesheet, width, height, true);
    }

    animation.setFrames(image);
    animation.setDelay(10);
}
```

But when I use

```
 image[i] = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(spritesheet, width, height, true);
```

everything is OK, but what if I want to add animated object?

Comment: decodeResource() scales the image to your device resolution already. Put the image in assets instead.

Comment: Thanks, I will check this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.
Should set the inScaled to false.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inScaled = false;
screen = new Screen(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.rain2, options), 40*WIDTH_X/1080, 200*HEIGHT_Y/1920, 1000,1000, 1);
```

As here it was also described:
[How to resize Bitmaps the optimal way in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741072/how-to-resize-bitmaps-the-optimal-way-in-android)